# Splitting string between capital and lowercase character in R?

Tags: r, string

I have a vector of character strings:

```
v1 <- c("Firstname LastnameFirstname Lastname", 
"Firstname Lastname", 
"Firstname Lastname", 
"Firstname LastnameFirstname Lastname")
```

I'd like to split the string between lowercase letter followed by a capital letter retaining both of the letters.

The desired output would be:

```
[1] "Firstname Lastname" "Firstname Lastname"   "Firstname Lastname"  "Firstname Lastname"  "Firstname Lastname" "Firstname Lastname"
```

Following examples in StackExchange I've tried with the `strsplit` function with `gsub`:

```
unlist(strsplit( gsub("([a-z][A-Z])","\\1~",v1), "~" ))
```

but this does not split **between** the characters, rather after the regex match for split point:

```
[1] "Firstname LastnameF" "irstname Lastname"   "Firstname Lastname"  "Firstname Lastname"  "Firstname LastnameF" "irstname Lastname"
```

How do I split between the characters still retaining both of the characters?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can use regex lookaround to match lower case letters (positive lookbehind - `(?<=[a-z])`) followed by upper case letters (positive lookahead -`(?=[A-Z])`)

```
unlist(strsplit(v1, "(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])", perl = TRUE))
#[1] "Firstname Lastname" "Firstname Lastname" "Firstname Lastname" 
#[4] "Firstname Lastname" "Firstname Lastname" "Firstname Lastname"
```