# How to split strings that mix upper and lowercase?

Tags: r, regex, perl, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I have a set of strings of the form:

```
Team XYZJohn SMITH / Jane SMITH
TEAM RacersJim SMITH / Jane SMITH
John McMahon RacingBob SMITH / Jane SMITH
```

and want to split on the joined names to give strings like:

```
Team XYZ :: John SMITH / Jane SMITH
TEAM Racers :: Jim SMITH / Jane SMITH
John McMahon Racing :: Bob SMITH / Jane SMITH
```

I'm in R, using Perl, but it's the regex I'm after.

Via https://stackoverflow.com/a/43706490/454773, this works for `TEAM RacersJohn SMITH / Jane SMITH`:

```
paste(strsplit('TEAM RacersJohn SMITH / Jane SMITH', "(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])", perl = TRUE)[[1]], collapse=' :: ')
```

but obviously gives an unwanted split in `McMahon` and misses the split in `Team XYZJohn`.

For things like `McMahon`, I was thinking a heuristic of *don't split on `[A-Z][a-z]{1,2}[A-Z]`* which would also cope with eg `MacDonald`.

Test on:

```
#Team XYZ :: John SMITH / Jane SMITH
#TEAM Racers :: John SMITH / Jane SMITH
#John McMahon Racing :: John SMITH / Jane SMITH
regex="(?<![A-Z][a-z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])"
print(paste(strsplit('Team XYZJohn SMITH / Jane SMITH', regex, perl = TRUE)[[1]], collapse=' :: '))
print(paste(strsplit('TEAM RacerJim SMITH / Jane SMITH', regex, perl = TRUE)[[1]], collapse=' :: '))
print(paste(strsplit('John McMahon RacingBob SMITH / Jane SMITH', regex, perl = TRUE)[[1]], collapse=' :: '))
```

Via @graemefowler on Twitter, we have:  `s/^(.+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)([A-Z]\w+ [A-Z]+ \/.+)/$1 :: $2/;`

```
print(gsub("^(.+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)([A-Z]\\w+ [A-Z]+ \\/.+)", "\\1 :: \\2", "TEAM RacersJohn SMITH / Jane SMITH", perl=TRUE))
print(gsub("^(.+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)([A-Z]\\w+ [A-Z]+ \\/.+)", "\\1 :: \\2", "Team XYZJohn SMITH / Jane SMITH", perl=TRUE))
print(gsub("^(.+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)([A-Z]\\w+ [A-Z]+ \\/.+)", "\\1 :: \\2", "John McMahon RacingJohn SMITH / Jane SMITH", perl=TRUE))


[1] "TEAM Racers :: John SMITH / Jane SMITH"
[1] "Team XYZ :: John SMITH / Jane SMITH"
[1] "John McMahon Racing :: John SMITH / Jane SMITH"
```

Comment: Maybe `\B(?<![A-Z][a-z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])`

Comment: Via @graemefowler on twitter:

` s/^(.+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)([A-Z]\w+ [A-Z]+ \/.+)/$1 :: $2/;`

Answer (score 1):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/ytBofK/2) might help you to get one target group <kbd>space</kbd>+<kbd>SMITH</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>:

```
 \s[A-Z]+\s\/
```

#### Output

[image]

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/mtdgfh/2) might help you to get two target groups and you can use a string replace to place an <kbd>space</kbd> before group 1 and a <kbd>space</kbd>+<kbd>::</kbd> prior to group two:

[image]